# CakePHP 3.0 - Console does not contain Schema shell

Tags: shell, database-schema, cakephp-3.0

I want to use the Schema shell (in CakePHP 3.0) to create my database but when I try to run the following command it gives me an error.

**Command**

> bin\cake schema generate

**Error**

> Exception: Shell class for "Schema" could not be found. in [D:\private_html\myApplication\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Console\ShellDispatcher.php, line 254]

I took a look at this page (so I could create the schema's manually): [CakePHP-3.0 Schema System](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/schema-system.html), but it does not tell me in which directory to put those files.

Comment: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#schemashell-removed**

Comment: @ndm Mmmm sad. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was replaced by this official plugin:

https://github.com/cakephp/migrations

It offers a more robust solution to schema migrations and initial schema dumping.

Comment: I couldn't find how to restore from a dump in this plugin